# Json Array is undefined in the second for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a Json with urls to pictures and a corresponding number. I am running it through two for loops, which works fine in the first one, but not in the second. Can you tell me why it shows me 'undefined' in the second one?

```
   {
    "sources": [
        {"pic": "../img/Bild1.png", "number": "1"},
        {"pic": "../img/Bild2.png", "number": "2"},

        {"pic": "../img/Bild9.png", "number": "9"},
        {"pic": "../img/Bild10.png","number": "10"}
]
}
```

```js
var url = "../js/Bildquelle.json";
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhttp.readyState === 4 && xhttp.status === 200) {
    var json = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
    gameStart(json.sources);

  }
};
xhttp.open("GET", url, true); //Resource beziehen, true= synchron
xhttp.send(); //Anfrage abschicken


function gameStart(Bildquelle) {


  // Create the pile of shuffled cards in random order
  Bildquelle.sort(function() {
    return Math.random() - .5
  });


  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var Karte = $('<img src=' + Bildquelle[i].pic + ' alt="Bild">').data('number', Bildquelle[i].number).attr('id', 'card' + Bildquelle[i].number).appendTo('#cardPile').draggable({
      containment: '#content',
      stack: '#cardPile img',
      cursor: 'move',
      revert: true
    })
  };


  // Create the card slots
  var number = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
  for (var j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
    var Kartenslot = $('<div></div>').data('number', j).appendTo('#cardSlots').css('background-image', 'url(' + Bildquelle[j].pic + ')').attr('id', 'slot' + number[j - 1]).droppable({
      accept: '#cardPile img',
      hoverClass: 'hovered',
      drop: handleCardDrop
    });
  }

};
```

Comment: you are using same variable `i` two times in same page

Comment: Is it because you're using `i` for both loops? Try changing the second loop to `var j = 0`.

Comment: You're accessing elements 0-9 of `Bildquelle` in the first loop and elements 1-10 in the second loop. This requires `Bildquelle` to have at least 11 elements, does it?

Comment: oh thanks for ponting it out, that was a stupid mistake. Sadly it is still showing the same error

Answer (score 0):

If `es6` support available, use `let i` instead of `var i` or change `var name in second for`.

`var` create `scope` to function level.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the variable `i` in both loops.
Try to change the variable of the second loop for another one or trying using [block scoping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)

```
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        /* i is defined here */ 
    }
    /* i is not defined here * /
```

This will give you the option to declare the variable `i` in both loops without errors.

Comment: Tried and chagend that, thanks for pointing it out. But it still shows me the same error

Comment: Show us an example of the Json used in the method gameStart, so we will be able to you the right solution easily :)

Comment: Hey Nina! Sorry for the delay. Have you managed to make it work?
If not, could you please tell me why you need to do 2 loops instead of 1? Maybe we can optimize it a little doing both things in one loop.

Comment: @Nina another advice would be trying to make sure that you loop through all the possible results doing that: for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) ...
With "arrayvar.length" you will get the number of iterations you will be able to do for that array and you will avoid possible errors.

Comment: Sorry I should have told you, but I fand a way to work around the problem, and the solution is really different to the original so problem. But thank you all